# Conditions in SUM function

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a `User` entity with `one-to-many` relationship with `Certificate` entity (one user might have multiple certificates). 
A `Certificate` has a `startDate` and `endDate` which determine their period of validity. I need filter all the users, that have expired certificates and have no active certificates.
An active certificate - `c.startDate <= :today AND c.endDate > :today`
An expired certificate - `c.endDate <= :today`.

I now how to do it in plain SQL:

```
SELECT
  u.user_id
FROM `User` u JOIN `Certificate` c ON c.user_id = u.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_id
HAVING SUM(c.end_date > :today) = 0
```

Now I'm trying to port the SQL query to Doctrine QueryBuilder syntax:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder();
$qb
    ->from('SomeNS:User', 'u')
    ->select('u')
    ->join('u.certificates', 'c')
    ->groupBy('u.id')
    ->having('SUM(c.endDate > :today) = 0')
    ->setParameter('today', $today);
```

But an error occurs:

> Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got '<'

It looks like the conditions in the SUM function aren't understood by Doctrine.
Please help to figure out how one can use conditions in SUM function or point me out what I do wrong.

Comment: Have you tried using the query builder expressions as described here http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html ? If not, I can post an aswer to show you how they work for your case.

Comment: However this condition doesn't really make sense: 'SUM((c.endDate <= :today)) > 0 AND SUM((c.endDate > :today)) = 0' because it can't satisfy both sums simultaneously :)

Comment: BTW It's allright with conditions =) Note that the comparisson signs are diffrent - `SUM((c.endDate <= :today)) > 0` - to make sure that a user has expired certificates and `SUM((c.endDate > :today)) = 0` - to make sure that  the user has no active certificates.

Comment: 1. If you know how to get what you need in pure sql and you don't need the whole object just do it this way.
2. Actually it doesn't seem there is need to do LEFT JOIN if Users set depends on Certificates. Do INNER JOIN instead and you will get what you need.

Comment: @Alex 
1. It's part of big filtering function with many filtering conditions and i should to use QueryBuilder as the another conditions do    
2.yes, you absolutly right with LEFT JOIN, it is mistake.

Comment: And one more point: sum() conditions look ugly.

Comment: @Alex, why ugly =)? It's just one of possible ways, I've also tryed COUNT(IF(conditions, 1, NULL)) - it works too

Comment: @Alex but yeah you are right it's ugly. The aim of the query has nothing to do with sum =)

Comment: @basilup, just because it might be done without this condition - but only with simple join and where condition by certificate dates. Finally you need something like this: "select u.user_id from users u join certificates c on c.user_id = u.user_id where c.endDate <= now()"

Comment: @Alex the point is that I need select users that have certificates, but there aren't active ones among them (all user certificates expired). And it is exactly two conditions - 1. a user has at least one certificate (it's covered by INNER JOIN) 2. a user has no active certificates - this conditions must guarantee that all the certificates are expired (it's what I tried to do with this ugly SUM).
The query you've suggested doesn't guarantee that selected users have no active certificates ( they might have both active and expired )

Comment: Your query answers the question "Which users do have expired certificates?", I try answer the question "Which users do have *JUST* expired certificates".

Comment: I feel stupid but I don't get what you mean. It looks unnatural to pass result of comparison into sum() function. And if "just expired" certificates are those once whose endDate more than current date (or more than current date minus, say, 1 hour (or 1 minute)), why do you need sum()? It seems you need to compare current date and certificate endDate. The rest will be done by join.
Maybe I just don't understand your question (but I think I do). Then just ignore my comment. O r we could talk in chat, if you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90337/discussion-between-basilup-and-alex).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a concrete answer using the expr() method of queryBuilder:

```
---
->having(
  $qb->expr()->andx( // this is the "AND" in between the sums
    $qb->expr()->lte( // this is the "<="
      ...(your SUM here, after you fix the logic),
      0
    ),
    $qb->expr()->eq( // this is the "="
      ...(your SUM here, after you fix the logic),
      0
    )
  )
)
```

Once you get those "SUM" conditions right, you put them in the placeholders and it should work.

Comment: Still have the same error. Have tryed different combinations, but with no results yet.

Comment: I inserted SUMs in your post, and now it's the expression that I've tried and that produces error. But it under peer review now.